# How to get POM property from org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am traversing a dependency graph of my main pom in a plugin using `org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph()` and the resulting `org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyNode`

However, once I reach a dependency with a specific groupId I need to access a maven property declared in its pom. How can I access the pom via the *Artifact* or the *DependencyNode* object?

Comment: Are you writing a plugin or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. that's why it has the maven-plugin tag

Comment: I edited the question to make that clear

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this groovy style .... (using a script written for [GMaven](http://gmaven.codehaus.org/))

I'll use as an example Javascript dependencies provided by webjars.org in which I want to read the (unfortunatly optional, as I've just discovered) `requirejs` property.

```groovy
/**
 * Read the requirejs property in pom (if possible) or in file (if not available in pom)
 * @param log the logger injected into the groovy script
 * @param project the MavenProject object (well, not really, but anyway a good implementor)
 * @param session the MavenSession
 * @param artifact the artifact in which we want to read the requirejs property
 */
def readRequireJSPropertyOf(def log, def project, def session, def artifact) {
    // This is the hardest part : the session gives access (through MavenSession#getContainer()) to the PlexusContainer, which allows lookup of various components
    MavenProjectBuilder projectBuilder = session.container.lookup(MavenProjectBuilder.class);
    // Now we have a MavenProjectBuilder, just build a MavenProject object
    MavenProject artifactProject = projectBuilder.buildFromRepository(artifact, project.remoteArtifactRepositories, session.localRepository);
    log.debug "loaded project ${artifactProject}. Now reading its requirejs property"
    // And read that property from artifact POM
    def requireValue = artifactProject.properties["requirejs"];
    return requireValue
}
```

Again, I can't emphasize enough on how the access to `PlexusContainer` saved day, aside the knowledge that the [`MavenProjectBuilder`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-compat/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectBuilder.html) component existed somewhere. Notice this component is deprecated and available through maven-compat artifact.